# Only show Google Analytics for my live domain

Tags: google-analytics

In my google analytics account it is showing data from my local testing server. I've also got a fairly popular tutorial/demonstration on my site, that people copy the whole source code and put on there site without removing my google tracking code. So i'm getting info about their traffic.

I've had a look through the settings and couldn't find anything relevant. Is there some sort of filter I can apply to show more accurate results.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an [include filter](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55492).

Filter type: custom -> include

Filter field: Hostname

Filter pattern: yourdomain\.com

Case sensitive: no

Note that you can have multiple excludes filters but only one include filter per profile.

And, you should always create a different profile for filters. **Keep a separate raw profile with no filters.**

Comment: Thanks for the tips jen! I've added in the filter, and will let you know how the indexing goes.

Comment: I checked today and the new profile i set up has a little clock icon instead of a tick, with no stats. Also i used the syntax yourdomain.com not yourdomain\.com will this make a difference?

Comment: Yes, the backslash matters. It's a filter pattern - regular expression - that is in that field. In edit filter, click on "Filter Help: Include   >   Hostname" and it will explain it.

Comment: Thanks Jen. I've just updated it, so should see some data in there soon. I'll let you know how I go. Cheers!